# Fuzzy flood fill in ImageMagic php - making a transparent image

Tags: php, algorithm, colors, background, imagemagick

I am working on a script that removes background color with a transparent color.

The script goes like this and gives results that are ok, discriminating fuchsia color.

```
        $val = 65535/40;
        //divide by fuzz dilution, 1 is none
        $val = floatval($val/0.9);
        //create white border
        $image->borderImage ( "rgb(255,255,255)" , 1 , 1 );
        //make all white fill fuchsia 
        $image->floodFillPaintImage ( "rgb(255, 0, 255)" ,$val*3, "rgb(255,255,255)", 0 , 0, false);
        //make fuchsia transparent
        $image->paintTransparentImage("rgb(255,0,255)", 0.0, 0.5); 
        //remove border 1px that was added above
        $image->shaveImage ( 1 , 1 );
```

However, it leaves traces of the color surrounding the image. Here's an example  of when i'm trying to remove borders around the phone with a white background - you can clearly see traces of white on the edges.

[image]

The problem is - when doing a flood fill on pixel 0,0, the background color gets colored wrong, i would need a "fuzzy" bucket fill function. The Imagemagic provides "fuzzy" algorithm for *floodFillPaintImage*, but the parameter of the 'fuzzy' part only serves as a selection of pixels, not fuzzy coloring as well.

For example, i have a 100% white - the algorithm correctly selects the perfectly white background and fills it with a new, perfectly fuchsia image. When you set a "fuzzy" parameter, the algorithm correctly **selects** 80% white pixels (for example), but colors it with 100% fuchsia again. that's where the problems with the ugly corners arise.

Does ImageMagic support something like "true" fuzzy flood fill and "true" fuzzy paintTransparentImage? Or does someone have a better idea on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a little go at this. I can't say I am 100% happy with it but it I have explained what I am doing and done tiny steps, so you could play around with each of the steps and fiddle with the numbers. I just did it at the command line for simplicity. It could all be simplified and speeded up if you get to a point where it does what you want.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get size of original
sz=$(convert -format "%wx%h" phone.png info:)

# Floodfill background area with transparency
convert phone.png -fuzz 5% -fill none -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' ObjectOnTransparent.png

# Extract alpha channel
convert ObjectOnTransparent.png -alpha extract Alpha.png

# Extract edges of alpha channel - experiment with thickness
convert Alpha.png -edge 1 AlphaEdges.png

# Get difference from background for all pixels
convert phone.png \( +clone -fill white -colorize 100% \) -compose difference -composite Diff.png

# Multiply edges with difference, so only edge pixels will have a chance of getting through to final mask
convert AlphaEdges.png Diff.png -compose multiply -composite EdgexDiff.png

# Extend Alpha by differences at edges
convert Alpha.png EdgexDiff.png -compose add -composite ReEdgedAlpha.png

# Apply new alpha to original image
convert phone.png \( ReEdgedAlpha.png -colorspace gray \) -compose copyopacity -composite RemaskedPhone.png

# Splat RemaskedPhone over red background
convert -size $sz xc:red RemaskedPhone.png -composite Result.png
```

**ObjectOnTransparent.png**

[image]

**Alpha.png**

[image]

**AlphaEdges.png**

[image]

**Diff.png**

[image]

**EdgexDiff.png**

[image]

**ReEdgedAlpha.png**

[image]

**Result.png**

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your help, it did indeed help me to get started on the problem. however, the EdgexDiff.png sometimes genertes borders that are too thin with some images. it is definitely better than my primitive approach but still not doing very good

Comment: can you guide me to set up the last command? it's not executing don't know why.

Comment: it is working perfectly for white background images, can you tell me how to do it if image have any background color like black or red ?

Comment: @mobeen Please just ask a new question (questions and answers are free) - include  images that don't work and a link to this answer for reference.

Comment: it is working perfectly for white background images, can you tell me how to do it if image have any background color like black or red ? attaching image with black background [link](https://ibb.co/BNWnNBs), how to remove outside black color ?