# remove background(any color) from image using image magick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

Hi I am asking this with reference to this question [Fuzzy flood fill in ImageMagic php - making a transparent image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089196/fuzzy-flood-fill-in-imagemagic-php-making-a-transparent-image/)

```
 #!/bin/bash

# Get size of original
sz=$(convert -format "%wx%h" phone.png info:)

# Floodfill background area with transparency
convert phone.png -fuzz 5% -fill none -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' ObjectOnTransparent.png

# Extract alpha channel
convert ObjectOnTransparent.png -alpha extract Alpha.png

# Extract edges of alpha channel - experiment with thickness
convert Alpha.png -edge 1 AlphaEdges.png

# Get difference from background for all pixels
convert phone.png \( +clone -fill white -colorize 100% \) -compose difference -composite Diff.png

# Multiply edges with difference, so only edge pixels will have a chance of getting through to final mask
convert AlphaEdges.png Diff.png -compose multiply -composite EdgexDiff.png

# Extend Alpha by differences at edges
convert Alpha.png EdgexDiff.png -compose add -composite ReEdgedAlpha.png

# Apply new alpha to original image
convert phone.png \( ReEdgedAlpha.png -colorspace gray \) -compose copyopacity -composite RemaskedPhone.png

# Splat RemaskedPhone over red background
convert -size $sz xc:red RemaskedPhone.png -composite Result.png
```

I ran these scripts and it is running accurate on images with white background and it is producing clean edges, but I want to ask if there is any way that I can remove any color background from an image like this image  https://ibb.co/BNWnNBs   from which I want to remove the black color from corners of image like this https://ibb.co/x7nD8Vb.

Any help is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 4):

This works for me in ImageMagick 6 in Unix syntax.

Input:

[image]

```
convert eagle.png -alpha off -fuzz 10% -fill none -draw "matte 0,0 floodfill"  \
\( +clone -alpha extract -blur 0x2 -level 50x100% \) \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \
eagle_transp.png
```

Result:

[image]

Windows Syntax would be:

```
convert eagle.png -alpha off -fuzz 10% -fill none -draw "matte 0,0 floodfill"  ^
( +clone -alpha extract -blur 0x2 -level 50x100% ) ^
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite ^
eagle_transp.png
```

If in .bat script, double the `%` to `%%`

Comment: I tired this and changed "matte 0,0 floodfill" to "alpha 0,0 floodfill" in this command because i have version 7, its not working for many white background images, here is the link of image <https://ibb.co/Y8Wf1hs> only top left part is converted to transparent the rest is ot converted can you suggest something here. Attaching same image on background for demo purpose <https://prnt.sc/1ysr8an>

Comment: Either put a white border around the image before applying the above or move the flood fill seed point to the upper right corner

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question about the new image, that image is different in two ways. First, the background under the transparent pixels is not fully white. Second the white area does not go all around the image. So in ImageMagick, you need to do two extra steps.

Input:

[image]

You can see the first issue by turning alpha off on the image:

```
magick target-transp.png -alpha off target-transp_alpha_off.png
```

[image]

Note the black area in the top left corner. So in the processing we need to change that black area to white.

Second, as you can see in the above image, the white are does not go all around the image. So we need to pad the image with a border of white that is 1 pixel wide on all sides.

Thus you can do one of two processes:

1. Flood fill the white

   ```
    magick target-transp.png \
    -background white -alpha background -alpha off \
    -bordercolor white -border 1 \
    -fuzz 10% -fill none -draw "alpha 0,0 floodfill"  \
    \( +clone -alpha extract -blur 0x2 -level 50x100% \) \
    -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \
    -shave 1x1 \
    target-transp_proc1.png
   ```

[image]

2. or make all white pixels transparent including inside some of letters such as the insides of "a" and "e"

   ```
    magick target-transp.png \
    -background white -alpha background -alpha off \
    -bordercolor white -border 1 \
    -fuzz 10% -transparent white  \
    \( +clone -alpha extract -blur 0x2 -level 50x100% \) \
    -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \
    -shave 1x1 \
    target-transp_proc2.png
   ```

[image]

You will need to download the resulting images to see the differences.

Comment: Thanks for your help @fmw42, the script is now working for white and non-white backgrounds, but can you tell me while removing white from the edges there is some blur factor added on the edges as you can see in your last image also?

Comment: I changed the blur statement to -blur 0x1, and now it is working almost accurate, thanks again for the help :)

Comment: You can drag the images in-browser, over other text, to see a slight indication of the difference, although with extra transparency applied.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are filling with transparency, then change**

```
convert phone.png -fuzz 5% -fill none -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' ObjectOnTransparent.png
```

to

```
convert phone.png -fuzz 5% -fill none -draw 'matte 0,0 floodfill' ObjectOnTransparent.png
```

**Then to antialias the edges, change**

```
convert phone.png \( ReEdgedAlpha.png -colorspace gray \) -compose copyopacity -composite RemaskedPhone.png
```

to

```
convert phone.png \( ReEdgedAlpha.png -colorspace gray -blur 0x2 -level 50x100% \) -compose copyopacity -composite RemaskedPhone.png
```

**ADDITION**

You wrote:

> I changed the steps and ran commands but it is not removing the outer
> black color instead the image is the same

Input:

[image]

So, increase the fuzz value and move the flood fill seed point slightly away from the upper left corner

```
convert Remasked-Phone.png -fuzz 30% -fill none -draw 'matte 3,3 floodfill' ObjectOnTransparent.png
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I changed the steps and ran commands but it is not removing the outer black color instead the image is the same <https://ibb.co/0c15sYw> can you suggest something? I want to remove outer black background like this <https://ibb.co/x7nD8Vb>

Comment: I am getting my same result with the command I showed.  What is your Imagemagick version and platform/OS?. If you are on IM 7, use magick rather than convert and change matte to alpha.